# Regex multi match on string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match multiple values with one regular expression.

I want to extract the flag and the value if it's present, however I want to provide the ability to the user to type the flag in multiple different ways.

```
npm start search
npm start search=test-string
npm start search="test"
npm start search='test'
npm start search="test, test-string"
npm start search=' test,test '
```

I want to be able to dissect the flag and the value after `=`, after equal it can be just one word or multiple values separated by a comma in single or double quotes.

here's what I've tried

```
(^[^=]+)\=([^'"].*)?
```

(in bold) is what I'm trying to match, group 1 would be the keyword, and group 2 would be the search value which is optional.

npm start **search**

npm start **search**=**test-string**

npm start **search**="**test**"

npm start **search**='**test**'

npm start **search**="**test, test-string**"

npm start **search**=' **test,test** '

I've tried using negative lookahead and behind but keep failing...

Comment: Is `=` supposed to be optional?

Comment: Yes, the value size of the flag is optional, the flag can be present without the value (=)

Comment: You don't have `?` after `=`, so it's not optional.

Comment: I know but it's not in a match group and the first match will match everything until the = sign

Comment: But there won't be any match at all if the `=` isn't matched, so no capture group is set.

Comment: It does match the flag mate, https://regex101.com/r/4wGMF6/1, the issue I'm not having is everything after the = sign

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you're seeing `^(^[^=\n]+)\=?` will match all flags, now I need to figure out all values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `=` optional.

If you want to allow quotes around the value, but not include them in the second capture group, put the quotes *before* the capture group and make them optional. Then match anything except quotes inside the capture group.

```
^([^=\n]+)=?['"]?([^'"\n]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zvphYw/3)

In the demo I removed the quotes from the strings, since those are parsed by the shell and not passed to npm. I also had to put `\n` in the `[^]` so it wouldn't match across multiple lines.

Comment: Hi mate, thankyou so far, i definitely need the examples I've sent, the script that's running is happening before the npm script runs (stupid abstraction) so I definitely need both single and double quotes working...

Comment: this is the closest I've come: https://regex101.com/r/zvphYw/1, but it's still matching the single quotes in group 2

Comment: So you're trying to parse the script that contains the `npm` commands, you're not doing this in the Javascript that's run by `npm`?

Comment: In that case you shouldn't have `^` at the beginning of the regexp, since you're trying to match things that aren't at the beginning of the line.

Comment: It's processed by node first, hard to explain, i'm not including `npm start ` in my examples as a simpler example to start with, it's easy to add that in later

Comment: Perfect, that's got it! Even though your examples don't include quotes it's working :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
(?<=npm start)([^=\n]+)(?:=?)(?:['"]+)?([^\n\'\"]+)?(?:[^\S\n]?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/i0aacp/10/

Comment: This is matching the flag and all the values in one group, also it's matching the quotes too.  https://regex101.com/r/4wGMF6/3 this is close, however it's stil matching quotes

Comment: thankyou, this works however @barmar's version is much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you the flag and value aftr stripping the quotes from the value:

```
 myStr.match (/^npm start ([^\s]+)\s*=?\s*(['"]?[^'"]+?['"]?)\s*?$/i)
```

Or with quotes

```
myStr.match (/^npm start ([^\s]+)\s*=?\s*([^\s]+)?\s*$/i)
```

If you don't need to match `npm start` simply

```
  myStr.match (/\s*([^\s]+)\s*=?\s*([^\s]+)\s*?$/i)
```

Haven't tested yet might need more tweaking.